# Can Thinset be used for covering cement driveway or garage cracks and small holes?

Tags: concrete

I have small holes and cracks in my cement driveway and garage floor. Can thinset be used to level these floors?

Comment: Sure it can be used.  But it won't last!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best option for the problem.

[image]
This product may help

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of crack seal would work too.  It looks like most of these are latex of some sort so perhaps that helps it to stick to the crack rather than chipping away and letting water back in.  [https://www.amazon.com/Quikrete-Concrete-Crack-Seal-Natural/dp/B000FCCZFQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FCCZFQ)